# What is the difference between PropertyChangeListener and VetoableChangeListener?

Tags: java

Everything is in the title of the question. 
Can you provide some use case we use PropertyChangeListener and VetoableChangeListener ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference resides in the fact that `PropertyChangeListener` are applied to *bound* properties while `VetoableChangeListener` are applied to *constrained* properties.

A *bound property* is just a property, while a *constrained* property is a property on which listeners can express themselves about a change that is going to be made: they can refuse this change from happening.

What it actually happens is that when you notify a vetoable property change you will do something like

```
VetoableChangeSupport vcs;
vcs.fireVetoableChange(...);
```

and this can throw a `PropertyVetoException` which will tell your bean that an observer wishes to block this property change (it should be rolled back).

Answer (score 1):

A [VetoableChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeListener.html) can veto (forbid) the property change. It will be rolled back if the receiver wishes. You may also attach constraints to the changed property.